# How does vacuum state look in first quantization?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, second-quantization

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_quantization#Second_quantized_Fock_states) says that the vacuum state is the unit of tensor product. In my understanding then, a first-quantized wavefunction for the vacuum state would be just constant in the each particle's configuration space. But this is a state where all the particles are present and have uniform probability density to be found anywhere.

If all particles are present, then how does this define a $0$-particle state?

Comment: Do you mean that the mathematical description has to introduce an infinite number of infinite dimensional subspaces to allow for the description of an arbitrary field state, even though the wave function in every one of them is "empty"? Yes, I think that's an unfortunate side effect of that approach. It carries a lot of empty weight.

Comment: No, what I don't understand is how can a tensor product of non-zero wavefunctions represent a state where there's no particle present: any non-zero single-particle wavefunction is a wavefunction of a particle which _is_ present.

Comment: The vacuum is simply never empty, not even when there are no "real" particles in it. Please keep in mind what a "real" particle is: it's a set of quantum numbers. When you draw a line that represents a "moving particle", what you really mean is that the field in the point where the line originates loses that much charge, angular momentum etc. and gains the same charge etc. at the end of that line. Even when there are no "real" particles present, the field still fluctuates, these fluctuations simply do not lead to a permanent (in terms of measurement) change.

Comment: This is what I don't understand. Suppose we have a vacuum state in a two-particle Fock space of a bosonic field: it would have a wave function of $\psi_v(x_1)\psi_v(x_2)$. But this wavefunction says that there _are_ two particles, both of which are in state $|\psi_v\rangle$ — a contradiction! What is wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean! The vacuum state is represented by an additional complex scalar that is part of the direct sum of multi-particle tensor products.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The vacuum state is not part of the $n$-particle sectors of the Fock space, apart when $n=0$. To be more precise, given a single-particle Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$, define the $n$-particle space, $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$, by
$$\mathscr{H}_n=\underbrace{\mathscr{H}\otimes_{s/a}\dotsm\otimes_{s/a}\mathscr{H}_n}_n$$
where $s/a$ stand for either symmetrized or antisymmetrized tensor product. Then define the $0$-particle state as $\mathscr{H}_0=\mathbb{C}$. The Fock space is the direct sum
$$\Gamma_{s/a}(\mathscr{H})=\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty\mathscr{H}_n$$
As a matter of fact we can represent a vector of the Fock space as
$\psi=(\psi_0,\psi_1,\dotsc,\psi_n,\dotsc)$,
where each $\psi_n\in\mathscr{H}_n$, the $n$-particle space.

The vacuum $\Omega$ is, a normalized vector with only non-zero component in the $0$-particle space (the customary (unimportant) choice is to have it to be $1$):
$$\Omega= (1,0,\dotsc,0,\dotsc)$$
As a matter of fact, the vacuum is also orthogonal, in the Fock space, to any other $n$-particle vector (with $n>0$).

**edit (to incorporate the comments)**: Suppose you have two states $\psi,\phi\in\Gamma_{s/a}(\mathscr{H})$; then they sum componentwise (i.e. sum each n-particle sector components) $\psi+\phi=(\psi_0+\phi_0,\psi_1+\phi_1,\dotsc,\psi_n+\phi_n,\dotsc)$. So, given the vacuum state $\Omega$, and a 1-particle state $\psi=(0,\psi_1(x),0,\dotsc,0,\dotsc)$, their superposition is
$$\psi+\Omega=(1,\psi_1(x),0,\dotsc,0,\dotsc)$$
that has components on the vacuum and the 1-particle space.

Now this has to be normalized, if we want a meaningful superposition, suppose we choose a symmetric $\psi+\omega=(1/\sqrt{2},\psi_1(x)/\sqrt{2},0,\dotsc,0,\dotsc)$. This is normalized, because the norm of the Fock space is
$$\lVert\psi\rVert^2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\lVert\psi_n\rVert^2$$
The interpretation is that the state $\psi+\Omega$ has the probability 1/2 of being the vacuum (no particles), and the probability 1/2 of being a one particle state $\psi_1(x)$; as the usual superposition principle predicts.

Simply in the Fock space we have (infinite) vectors of states, that represent all the possible configurations of $n$-particles, and that in principle may coexist on the same state in the sense that we may have a certain probability of having either 0, 1, 2, or $n$ particles (with any $n$).

Comment: Could you elaborate how a superposition of vacuum state with one-particle-present state would look in position representation (in terms of single particle states $\psi_n(x)$)?

Comment: In the Fock space, such a state needs not to be a superposition. Let me explain: suppose you have two states $\psi,\phi\in\Gamma_{s/a}(\mathscr{H})$; then they sum componentwise (i.e. sum each $n$-particle sector components) $\psi+\phi=(\psi_0+\phi_0,\psi_1+\phi_1,\dotsc,\psi_n+phi_n,\dotsc)$. So, given the vacuum state $\Omega$, and a $1$-particle state $\psi=(0,\psi_1(x),0,\dotsc,0,\dotsc)$ their superposition is
$$\psi+\Omega=(1,\psi_1(x),0,\dotsc,0,\dotsc)$$
that has components on the vacuum and the 1-particle space...

Comment: Now this has to be normalized, if we want a meaningful superposition, suppose we choose a symmetric $\psi+\Omega=(1/\sqrt{2},\psi_1(x)/\sqrt{2},0,\dotsc,0,\dotsc)$
This is normalized, because the norm of the Fock space is $$\lVert \psi\rVert^2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lVert \psi_n\rVert^2$$
The interpretation is that the state $\psi+\Omega$ has the probability 1/2 of being the vacuum (no particles), and the probability 1/2 of being a one particle state ($\psi_1(x)$); as the usual superposition principle predicts. Simply in the Fock space we have (infinite) vectors of states, that represent all the

Comment: possible configurations of $n$-particles, and that in principle may coexist on the same state in the sense that we may have a certain probability of having either $0$, $1$, $2$, or $n$ particles (with any $n$). Hope this helps you clarify a little bit ;-)

Comment: Thanks, this does clarify a bit. One more thing I didn't understand completely: what if there're $n$ particles in the same state? Is the Fock state then like $(0,0,...,\psi_n(x_1,...,x_n),0,...)$? And then if we add another particle there, the non-zero position in this vector shifts to $n+1$ position while being tensor-multiplied by another single-particle state, right? So we'd have now $(0,0,...,0,\psi_n(x_1,...,x_n)\otimes\psi_1(x_{n+1}),0,...)$ (up to symmetrization).

Comment: PS: I think your comments are essential to fully understand your answer, could you put them into the answer body?

Comment: Ok, I will add them to the body as soon as I have time ;-) However your idea for adding a particle is ok, and that operation is actually done mathematically by the creation operator.